# How can I change Mac OS's default Java VM returned from /usr/libexec/java_home

Tags: java, macos, java-home

(Wasn't sure if this should go on SU... migration is certainly an option, but more programmers read questions here, so here goes).

I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4, and I have Apple's JDK 1.6.0_51 installed as well as Oracle's JDK 1.7.0_25. I recently installed Oracle's 1.8 preview JDK for some pre-release software that requires it. Now, when I run /usr/libexec/java_home, I get this:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    1.8.0, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_51-b11-457, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_51-b11-457, i386: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Great.

However, running:

```
$ java -version
```

Returns:

```
java version "1.8.0-ea"
```

That means that the default version of Java is currently the pre-release version, which breaks some "normal" packages (in my case, VisualVM).

I can't set `JAVA_HOME` because launching applications ignores environment variables, even when launching from the command line (e.g. `$ open /Applications/VisualVM.app`).

So, is there a file I can edit where I can set my JVM ordering preferences *globally*?

(Please don't tell me to launch the Java Preferences Panel because that simply does not work: it does not contain anything useful and only lists one of the 4 JVMs that I have installed.)

**Update**:

Oracle JVMs live in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. Re-naming the JDK 1.8 directory to `jdk1.8.0.jvm.xyz` does not change anything: `java_home` still finds it in the right place, and running /usr/bin/java still executes the 1.8 JVM. This is not an issue with synlinks, etc.

**Answers to Similar Questions**

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169445/1090666) offers what amounts to a hack that will remove versions of Java from being picked up by java_home, it still does not answer this question of *how* java_home chooses its default and whether or not users can [non-destructively set it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994919/1090666).

Comment: Type 'which java' and follow the breadcrumbs. `/usr/bin/java` is just a symlink

Comment: Been there, done that. `/usr/bin/java` points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`. The `Versions` directory does not contain a symlink to the 1.8.0 JDK. Instead, it contains a directory helpfully called `A` which `Current` points to. `A` is not a "JAVA_HOME. It has a subdirectory called `Commands` which does have a `java` command, but it is an opaque universal binary which does who-knows-what. I suspect it uses `java_home`, etc. to decide which JVM to use.

Comment: If this is off-topic, please migrate instead of closing. FWIW, this is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" so closing "off-topic" is disingenuous.

Comment: Yes, this is frustrating! I just want one JDK for all, or maybe 2 that I can switch between 1.7 and 1.8 easily.

Comment: I found this SO answer useful for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169445/2987755

Comment: For anyone who wants the value of /usr/libexec/java_home to match the current java installed/managed by SDKMAN, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76523554/328275

Answer (score 100):

I think `JAVA_HOME` is the best you can do.  The command-line tools like `java` and `javac` will respect that environment variable, you can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'` to give you a suitable value to put into `JAVA_HOME` in order to make command line tools use Java 7.

```
export JAVA_HOME="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'`"
```

But standard double-clickable application bundles don't use JDKs installed under `/Library/Java` at all.  Old-style `.app` bundles using Apple's `JavaApplicationStub` will use Apple Java 6 from `/System/Library/Frameworks`, and new-style ones built with [AppBundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler) without a bundled JRE will use the "public" JRE in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` - that's hard-coded in the stub code and can't be changed, and you can't have two different public JREs installed at the same time.

---

Edit: I've had a look at VisualVM specifically, assuming you're using the "application bundle" version from [the download page](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html), and this particular app is not an AppBundler application, instead its main executable is a shell script that calls a number of other shell scripts and reads various configuration files.  It defaults to picking the newest JDK from `/Library/Java` as long as that is 7u10 or later, or uses Java 6 if your Java 7 installation is update 9 or earlier.  But unravelling the logic in the shell scripts it looks to me like you can specify a particular JDK using a configuration file.

Create a text file `~/Library/Application Support/VisualVM/1.3.6/etc/visualvm.conf` (replace 1.3.6 with whatever version of VisualVM you're using) containing the line

```
visualvm_jdkhome="`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'`"
```

and this will force it to choose Java 7 instead of 8.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case on my system. Launching VisualVM before JDK 1.8 was installed worked. After JDK1.8, VisualVM shows the splash screen, then dies. Moving the JDK1.8 directory out of /Library/Java restores its ability to run.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I've had a look inside the VisualVM bundle and it turns out it's not a normal appbundler application.  See my edit for a possible workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my previous comment before your edit. I'll check-out getting VisualVM to run using that technique, but it's unlikely to be universally-applicable. I have a bunch of other Java-based software tat I run as well like Eclipse, JasperReports iReport, etc. that are all likely to be affected by this. I think I'd rather just move the JDK1.8 directory somewhere else and use that explicitly with JAVA_HOME for the (few) times that I actually need it.

Comment: Yup, you’re right, `JAVA_HOME` is the way to go and in general your best bet is to specify the minor version you need in other cases. Based on disassembly, it turns out you can `export JAVA_VERSION=1.7` to make `java_home` default to showing JKD7 instead of JDK8, but that breaks `java_home -v 1.6` because `java-home` interprets it as an additional constraint and gives up due to mutually unsatisfiable constraints, then just goes with the default 1.8 even with the `--failfast` option.

Comment: I can't understand why the System Preferences Java Control Panel doesn't just present a list to select from, rather than have to resort to shell scripts/commands. I suspect this is just for Applets that run in the browser...

Comment: @IanRoberts Hi, I have similar issue in bundling my Java application, I would be grateful if you could have a look at my question as well, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207295/failed-to-bundle-java-application-1-8-for-mac

Answer (score 67):

I've been there too and searched everywhere how `/usr/libexec/java_home` works but I couldn't find any information on how it determines the available Java Virtual Machines it lists.

I've experimented a bit and I think it simply executes a `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and then inspects the `./<version>/Contents/Info.plist` of all runtimes it finds there.

It then sorts them **descending** by the key `JVMVersion` contained in the Info.plist and by default it uses the first entry as its default JVM.

I think the only thing we might do is to change the plist: `sudo vi /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Info.plist` and then modify the JVMVersion from `1.8.0` to something else that makes it sort it to the bottom instead of the top, like `!1.8.0`.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <dict>
            ...
            <key>JVMVersion</key>
            <string>!1.8.0</string>   <!-- changed from '1.8.0' to '!1.8.0' -->`
```

and then it magically disappears from the top of the list:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -verbose
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_09, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
    !1.8.0, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now you will need to logout/login and then:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
```

:-)

**Of course I have no idea if something else breaks now or if the 1.8.0-ea version of java still works correctly.**

You probably should not do any of this but instead simply deinstall 1.8.0.

However so far this has worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I have had to use this tweak to keep the Idea Sbt plugin working for me on MacOS. I am mentioning it on my blog http://agilebuild.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-intellij-sbt-plugin-and-fighting.html

Comment: This works but it seems a little tricky and might not look like a standard operation procedure. I wander if there is a better approach.

Comment: I would still like a solution for this, but for setting the JDK for Intellij to use I added this to my zshenv: export IDEA_JDK=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`. I think I'll do the same for JAVA_HOME...

Comment: I manage to use this answer to avoid using Java 9 launching  double-click applications (due to an issue in Keystore Store explorer). Thanks!

Comment: An excerpt from [Installation of the JDK and the JRE on macOS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm): After installing Java for macOS 2012-006, `/usr/bin/java` will find the **newest** JDK installed, and will use that for all of the Java-related command-line tools in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Well, you're on to something! Of course, it'd be great to know if there is a way to do this in a way that the designers of the java_home executable intended. You know, like real documentation rather than the incredibly terse output of java_home -help. Sadly, it looks like java_home simply doesn't offer this functionality.

Comment: It seems like the tool also checks `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Instead of modifying the content of `Info.plist`, another option is to simply rename the file for versions that you _want to exclude_: `mv Info.plist Info.plist.disabled` (might need `sudo`). Undoing this is then as easy as renaming the file back.

Answer (score 15):

I actually looked at this a little in the disassembler, since source isn't available.

/usr/bin/java and /usr/libexec/java_home both make use of JavaLaunching.framework.  The JAVA_HOME environment variable is indeed checked first by /usr/bin/java and friends (but not /usr/libexec/java_home.)  The framework uses the JAVA_VERSION and JAVA_ARCH envirionment variables to filter the available JVMs.  So, by default:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.5, x86_64: "Amazon Corretto 11"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_232, x86_64:  "Amazon Corretto 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But setting, say, JAVA_VERSION can override the default:

```
$ JAVA_VERSION=1.8 /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can also set JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE=1 to see some additional debug logging as far as search paths, found JVMs, etc., with both /usr/bin/java and /usr/libexec/java_home.

In the past, JavaLaunching.framework actually used the preferences system (under the com.apple.java.JavaPreferences domain) to set the preferred JVM order, [allowing the default JVM to be set with PlistBuddy](https://gist.github.com/steakknife/3777782) - but as best as I can tell, that code has been removed in recent versions of macOS.  Environment variables seem to be the only way (aside from editing the Info.plist in the JDK bundles themselves.)

Setting default environment variables can of course be done through your .profile or via [launchd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586170/1009065), if you need them be set at a session level.

Comment: This is great information, Dan. Using `.profile` isn't useful for my use-case (launching an application from e.g. launchpad) but the tip on `launchd` is a good one. I'll have to give that a try, since Java's recent versioning madness means that I have several generations of Java installed simultaneously, with varying levels of (personal) trust.

Comment: This is great!  I am running a slightly convoluted Eclipse setup and have several JDKs installed.  So I just created a different BASH script for each Eclipse config I need that simply has the line:  "JAVA_VERSION=1.8 /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse &"

Comment: OMG this is the best answer, should be the first one. Thank you! So, what I have done after understanding that we can use JAVA_VERSION to change the default JVM returned by java_home is to "launchctl setenv JAVA_VERSION" with my preferred JVM and then you can just use "launchtl setenv JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`". Then JAVA_VERSION and JAVA_HOME will be available everywhere. You can always update the JAVA_VERSION and re-execute the script to update it everywhere instantly (you need to restart any application that use it obviously).

Comment: This answer is brilliant! Should be the top answer for sure. Setting `JAVA_HOME` is by far the simplest and most accurate approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

It's actually pretty easy.
Let's say we have this in our JavaVirtualMachines folder:

- jdk1.7.0_51.jdk
- jdk1.8.0.jdk

Imagine that 1.8 is our default, then we just add a new folder (for example 'old') and move the default jdk folder to that new folder.
Do `java -version` again et voila, 1.7!

Comment: Unbelievable, but it worked... Thanks Mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 8):

I tested "jenv" and other things like setting "JAVA_HOME" without success.
Now I ended up with following solution:

```
function setJava {
    export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)"
    launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME
    sudo ln -nsf "$(dirname ${JAVA_HOME})/MacOS" /Library/Java/MacOS 
    java -version
}
```

*(added to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash.profile or ~/.zshrc)*

And calling like that:

```
setJava 1.8
```

java_home will handle the wrong input. So you can't do something wrong.
Maven and other stuff will pick up the right version now.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to look at `launchctl setenv`. It's possible that will actually do the job.

Comment: zsh: command not found: setJava

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple, if you don't mind rolling up your sleeves... **/Library/Java/Home** is the default for JAVA_HOME, and it's just a link that points to one of:

- /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.?.?.jdk/Contents/Home
- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.?.?_??.jdk/Contents/Home

So I wanted to change my default JVM/JDK version **without** changing the contents of JAVA_HOME... /Library/Java/Home is the standard location for the current JVM/JDK and that's what I wanted to preserve... it seems to me to be the easiest way to change things with the least side effects.

It's actually really simple. In order to change which version of java you see with java -version, all you have to do is some version of this:

```
cd /Library/Java
sudo rm Home
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home ./Home
```

I haven't taken the time but a very simple shell script that makes use of /usr/libexec/java_home and ln to repoint the above symlink should be stupid easy to create...

Once you've changed where /Library/Java/Home is pointed... you get the correct result:

```
cerebro:~ magneto$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM)
64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This isn't how this stuff works: `/Library/Java/Home` is indeed a symlink, but it points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` which itself is in a big jumble of symlinks that finally gets you to ... a magical command that determines the right JRE to launch. Note that `/usr/libexec/java_home` also links into this magic. So, you can interrupt everything by just replacing symlinks and pointing to a single JRE, but you'll have to update that every time. There is evidently no command like `set_preferred_jvm_version` or something similar.

Comment: The advantage of this technique, though, is that it does not require you to set `JAVA_HOME` anywhere. I'll play with this technique to see if it will result in Java-based programs launching with the "preferred" Java VM. I suspect it will, but it's pretty fragile.

Comment: Well these days I just have this in `.bash_profile`: ``export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12` ``

Comment: This doesn't work for double-clicking on an icon, which was kind of the whole point. Solutions which only work from the command-line are ... not solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's [uninstallation instructions for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html) worked for me.

Excerpt:

> Uninstalling the JDK
>   To uninstall the JDK, you must have Administrator privileges and execute the remove command either as root or by using the sudo(8) tool.
>
> Navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines and remove the directory whose name matches the following format:*
>
> `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<major>.<minor>.<macro[_update]>.jdk`
>
> For example, to uninstall 7u6:
>
> `% rm -rf jdk1.7.0_06.jdk`

Comment: This question wasn't about un-installation... it was about choosing the "primary" JVM from those one has installed...

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but as this is an ongoing issue with Mac OSX...

The simplest solution I found was to simply remove the OpenJDK stuff that Apple installs. Every time an update of Mac OSX arrives it gets installed and you'll need to remove it again.

This works really well if you develop apps for Google App Engine on your mac using Java. The OpenJDK does not work well and the Java version that comes with the Mac OSX Yosemite upgrade will make the Eclipse Plug-in for App Engine crash on every deployment with the helpful error: "Read timed out".

Comment: Funny... I thought Apple had removed Java altogether at this point. I don't remember manually removing Apple's Java 1.6 JVM, and it's definitely no longer here. At any rate, this doesn't really fix the original problem which was to specify the preferred JVM given a selection that have been installed.

Comment: You are correct. It doesn't answer the question. It does answer this: If you remove the JVM being used, the 'next' one in the list is used. Maybe that helps.

Comment: does this explain why after running a jdk 8 install, it doesn't show up in the JavaVirtualMachines folder?  All I see is "1.6.0.jdk" no matter what version I install.

Comment: @whyoz Just installed jdk-8u31-macosx-x64 on osx 10.10.2 and the VM was installed in the JavaVirtualMachines folder as expected.

Comment: Are you running Parallels by chance?  I installed it on the Windows side of Parallels and 8u31 installed as expected..just not on the Mac side..

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: this information is for visualvm specifically, not for any other java app**

As mentioned by others, you need to modify the visualvm.conf

For the latest version of JvisualVM 1.3.6 on Mac, the install directories have changed.

It is currently in
**/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf**.

However this may depend on where you have installed VisualVM. The easiest way to find where your VisualVM is to start it, and then look at the process using:

ps -ef | grep VisualVM

You will see something like:

... **-Dnetbeans.dirs=/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/visualvm**...

You want to take the netbeans.dir property and look up a directory and you will find the etc folder.

Uncomment this line in the visualvm.conf and change the path to the jdk

```
visualvm_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Additionally, if you are having slowness with your visualvm and you have a lot of memory, I would suggest greatly increasing the amount of memory available and running it in server mode:

```
visualvm_default_options="-J-XX:MaxPermSize=96m -J-Xmx2048m -J-Xms2048m -J-server -J-XX:+UseCompressedOops -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+UseParNewGC -J-XX:NewRatio=2 -J-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.startup.AcceptLicense -J-Dsun.jvmstat.perdata.syncWaitMs=10000 -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false"
```

Comment: Bad advice: modifying the startup script for a particular application will likely break the application *and* does not solve the original problem of changing the default JVM for the OS.

Comment: Unfortunately as mentioned by others, jvisualvm does not use standard methods for choosing a jvm. This is the only solution for this app.

Comment: As I state in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17886334/592139) you don't need to modify anything inside the application bundle itself, the app can load its configuration from `~/Library/Application Support/VisualVM/1.3.6/etc/visualvm.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

To the point in question:
I would do this

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -- v x.y.z)

where x.y.z is the jdk version number.

Comment: This does not effect programs launched via Launchpad, `open`, etc. I specifically stated in the question that simply setting `JAVA_HOME` is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score -1):

the command /usr/libexec/java_home can search new java version.
egg. JD_GUI.app. in this application. i can't runable. so i find some script in /Applications/JD-GUI.app/Contents/MacOS/universalJavaApplicationStub.sh to search JAVA_HOME, i just get direct path. then runable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvr8J.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDy8.png)
then look like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEHbL.png)
just fun

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar situation, and the following process worked for me:

1. In the terminal, type

   ```
   vi ~/.profile
   ```
2. Then add this line in the file, and save

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```

   where version is the one on your computer, such as 1.7.0_25
3. Exit the editor, then type the following command make it become effective

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

Then type java -version to check the result

```
    java -version
```

What is .profile? 
From:http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/speed-up-your-terminal-workflow-with-command-aliases-and-profile--mac-30515

> .profile file is a hidden file. It is an optional file which tells the system which commands to run when the user whose profile file it is logs in. For example, if my username is bruno and there is a .profile file in /Users/bruno/, all of its contents will be executed during the log-in procedure.

Comment: This will not work when launching VisualVM from Launchpad. Launching from the command-line is never a problem, as you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score -2):

MacOS uses /usr/libexec/java_home to find the current Java Version.  One way to bypass is to change the plist file as explained by @void256 above. 
Other ways is to take the backup of the java_home and replace it with your own script java_home having the code
        echo $JAVA_HOME

Now export the JAVA_HOME to the desired version of the SDK by adding the following commands to the ~/.bash_profile.
        export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
        launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $JAVA_HOME      /// Make the environment variable global

Run the command source ~/.bash_profile to the run the above commands.

Anytime one needs to change the JAVA_HOME he can reset the JAVA_HOME value in the ~/.bash_profile file.

Comment: Anything that relies on environment variables will not work. The point is that applications launched via LaunchPad, etc. won't have that environmental setup. The plist hack above seems like the "best" one in that it actually achieves the desired result. I'm not sure about any downsides, yet. See the answer from @Tony which has the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Simplify the need :-)

Steps to changes --

Find the installed version on your machine by executing following command

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

then you might see like below if there are multiple version of JDK installed

```
11.0.16 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.16" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/blabla
1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/bala
```

Create Env file based your machine, for mac like below create or edit the your system Environment file either .zshenv, .zshprofile etc...

```
nano ~/.zshenv
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_292)
```

Then the magic is done, where ever this symlink used all those java refer to version which you set! Happy coding Boys & Girls.

Comment: This specifically does not work. Setting `JAVA_HOME` manually within a single Terminal process will work... *if* you launch your Java applications from the Terminal. I want to be able to launch from Launchpad, Finder, etc. where there is no `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score -3):

I wanted to change default java version form 1.6* to 1.7*. I tried the following steps and it worked for me:

- Removed link "java" from under /usr/bin
- Created it again, pointing to the new location:

ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java java

- verified with "java -version"

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Does not answer the question: it will not affect the behavior of `/usr/libexec/java_home`.