# Manually install JDK on Mac?

Tags: java, macos

I'm a longtime Java developer switching from Ubuntu to Mac: On my Linux development environment, I would untar different jdks to ~/opt/jdk and then setup a current soft link like this:

```
~/opt/jdk/jdk_1.7.0_51
~/opt/jdk/jdk_1.8.0_05
~/opt/jdk/current -> jdk_1.8.0_05
```

In `~/bin`, I had a `java` soft link that would point to `~/opt/jdk/current/bin/java`

If I wanted to switch JDKs for development, I would just switch the `current` link.

On Mac, I can only download .dmg files that contain installers. If I run more than one, it seems like the latter overwrites the existing install? Can't I simply download binary archives like on Linux?

Comment: I don't think it overrides, just changes what `java` points to.

Comment: Can you adopt [this scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6588390/230513)?

Comment: Do you need the setting to affect GUI apps that are launched from the Finder, or just stuff that you can run from a terminal session? And do you need to switch between minor versions, like 1.7.0_51 and 1.7.0_55, or just the major 1.7 vs 1.8 versions?

Comment: And which version of OS X are you on? Java support has changed significantly over the major OS revisions.

Comment: Also check out this one which has more details on how multiple installed JDKs work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885494/how-can-i-change-mac-oss-default-java-vm-returned-from-usr-libexec-java-home

Comment: I am on OS X 10.9.3. Thanks for the tips!