# Can't connect Hbase shell

Tags: java, hbase

I have installed Hbase 1.2.6 on Mac OS X 10.11.6 just for stand-alone testing purpose. 
I have configured the `hbase-site.xml` and the `hbase-env.sh`.
Giving the command `./hbase shell` to launch shell I am having the following error

```
    $ bin/hbase  shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker (file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar) to method java.lang.Object.registerNatives()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.java.invokers.RubyToJavaInvoker
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
  method_added at file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:10
  method_added at file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/javasupport/core_ext/object.rb:129
       Pattern at file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:2
        (root) at file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:1
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1062
        (root) at file:/Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/builtin/java/java.util.regex.rb:42
        (root) at /Users/user/Hbase/Hb126/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:38
```

Java version:

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

Jruby version:

```
jruby 9.1.15.0 (2.3.3) 2017-12-07 929fde8 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 9.0.4+11 on 9.0.4+11 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
```

Any help?

Comment: hbase version: Source code repository file:///home/busbey/projects/hbase/hbase-assembly/target/hbase-1.2.6 revision=Unknown

Comment: Have you tried a different Java version?

Comment: Yes, with Java 8 it works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hbase doesn't support Java 9 at this time.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-12081

Try setting a different `JAVA_HOME` in the `hbase-env`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was Java 9, with Java 8 the script works properly.
I have installed Java 8 and changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `conf/hbase-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885494/how-can-i-change-mac-oss-default-java-vm-returned-from-usr-libexec-java-home?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) SO answer, change the `JAVA_HOME` in `/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.2.6/libexec/conf/hbase-env` to

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*')"
```