# How to get NetBeans 12.0 to launch on Mac (MAC OS 11.0 beta / Big Sur)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

On Mac (Big Sur) when I click on the Netbeans 12 icon in the doc it bounces briefly then fails to launch Netbeans.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer helped me launch Netbeans from the terminal. I added this change to make my dock icon launch Netbeans like before.

I changed the Netbeans config file to make it launch with the Java path:

1. Like the previous post indicates find your JDK path with this command in the Terminal

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'
```

2. Now add this path to the Netbeans conf file. To do this:

- right click on the Netbeans icon in the dock and select Open in Finder
- in the smaller icon it shows right click again and select Show sources
- find the **netbeans.conf** file in folder **Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf**
- open this **netbeans.conf** file with a TextEditor or similar and find the line

```
#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

Uncomment this line and change it for your path (the one you found in point 1)
something like

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Save the *netbeans.conf* file and try and launch from the Dock icon

Comment: Thank you I spent a long time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Hey thanks @Gemma for providing the additional details from my original answer - launching directly from the dock is much nicer, thank you.  I've marked your answer as accepted as it's what I would have originally wanted 

Comment: It would be much better to change the line in `netbeans.conf` to: `netbeans_jdkhome="\`/usr/libexec/java_home\`"`.  That keeps the conf file working as is when Java is updated on the machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you right click on the icon in the dock --> Options --> Show in Finder the operating system will show you where 'Apache Netbeans 12.0' is located.

Highlight 'Apache Netbeans 12.0' then right-click and choose 'Show Package Contents', then you can find a shortcut that launches Netbeans (Contents/MacOS/netbeans).

If you double-click to launch netbeans you'll be presented with the following reason why it fails to load.

```
/Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans ; exit;
rob@Robs-MBP-2015 ~ % /Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans ; exit;
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports (null).
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

Credit goes to [How can I change Mac OS's default Java VM returned from /usr/libexec/java_home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885494/how-can-i-change-mac-oss-default-java-vm-returned-from-usr-libexec-java-home) for providing the following step to determine what the JDK path is...

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'
```

Then you can type the following (adjust for your path and version required)

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

However that didn't seem to do the trick for me (I also tried JDK_HOME), so instead from a Terminal window type the command to launch Netbeans but include the --jdkhome to your Java home folder, e.g.

```
/Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now I have Netbeans launching again.  I'm not quite sure why the JAVA_HOME doesn't resolve this, but hopefully in the meantime anyone unable to launch Netbeans can at least use this workaround.

I've also found this [How to run a shell script in OS X by double-clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking) useful to ensure I can double-click on the shell script to run it from a shortcut on my desktop.

Comment: Please see the comment from @Gemma - it provides extra details that gets the above working in the Dock 

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, some Netbeans versions for Mac OS do not detect the JDK contained in JRE. For proper installation and running the application,you must have *Java for Mac OS* installed previously.
https://www.java.com/es/download/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to macOS Big Sur from Mojave.

Before running commands in terminal, you could just try to reinstall Java for Mac OS X :

https://www.java.com/en/download/

It solves my issue. I am now able to launch NetBeans 12.1