# How to point /usr/libexec/java_home to custom jdk installation?

Tags: java, macos, zshrc

I'm on macOS monterrey and using a custom JDK 15 (I have to use a custom JDK modified for my company). When I run `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

however when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk_15.0.6_15.38.18_x64`. In addition running `java --version` return the correct JDK version.

Because `/usr/libexec/java_home` doesn't point to the actual JDK directory tools which use Java don't work.

Is there a way to set `/usr/libexec/java_home` to point to my JDK directory?

Answer (score 3):

What c4augustus uses as [a short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71830594/39642) almost worked for me. Uneasy part was figuring out the proper content of the linked directory – as found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169445/39642), `/usr/libexec/java_home` searches for `Info.plist` file located under `Contents/` dir.

And that is located in greater depth of OpenJDK structure (in my case) installed in the system by Homebrew. Simple re-linking to proper directory made the trick:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.jdk`

Hope this helps someone (I needed it for VS Code being able to handle PlantUML pictures inside AsciiDoc documents).

Comment: Running `brew install openjdk@17` provides this info: `For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk`
And more...

Answer (score 2):

See these questions for a deep dive into this topic:

[How can I change Mac OS's default Java VM returned from /usr/libexec/java_home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885494/how-can-i-change-mac-oss-default-java-vm-returned-from-usr-libexec-java-home)

[How to set or change the default Java (JDK) version on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos)

Here is a short answer that works:

```
sudo ln -s (absolute path to your JVM) /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/(symlink name)
```

In my case, it points to the JVM in the latest Android Studio:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/android-studio-jre
```