# How to make /usr/libexec/java_home find JDK installed using SDKMAN on MacOS?

Tags: xcode, sh, java-home, sdkman

I am making iOS apps in Kotlin, which relies on having a Script Build Phase calling Gradle from XCode. With a JDK installed using SDKMAN, it does not work and produces this error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

The JDK installed with SDKMAN is working correctly on my system, SDKMAN sets `JAVA_HOME` to `/Users/{user}/.sdkman/candidates/java/current` by sourcing its `sdkman-init.sh` script from `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`. But XCode Script Phase uses `/bin/sh`, and it does not seem to read these kinds of files.

I tried exporting `JAVA_HOME` in files like `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, etc. with no result.

After some research, I found that this output is from a call to `/usr/libexec/java_home` producing no result. I also found that manually calling `/usr/libexec/java_home` inside a Terminal where `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly does not pick it up, so toying with `JAVA_HOME` is useless in this case: it just doesn't read it.

So, how do you make the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command find JDK installed using SDKMAN on MacOS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `/usr/libexec/java_home` seems to be mostly undocumented, it's very hard to find information about how it works. Combining the little information about it found online and some trial and error, I managed to trick `/usr/libexec/java_home` into returning SDKMAN's current JDK.

There are 2 issues that we need to work around:

- SDKMAN-installed JDKs don't look like manually installed JDKs
- SDKMAN-installed JDKs are not in a location `/usr/libexec/java_home` knows

On MacOS, manually installed JDKs are installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and look like this (non-exhaustive):

```
jdk-root-folder/
  Contents/
    Info.plist
    Home/
      <actual JDK files here>
```

But SDKMAN only installs the actual JDK files. The solution is to fake everything SDKMAN does not install:

- Create a folder in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` for your JDK, I'll call mine `sdkman-current` but the name does not matter.
- Create a `Contents` folder inside `sdkman-current`
- Create a symlink named `Home` inside the `Contents` folder, linking to your actual JDK:

  ```bash
  sudo ln -s /Users/{REPLACE_ME}/.sdkman/candidates/java/current /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/sdkman-current/Contents/Home
  ```
- Create a `Info.plist` file in the `Contents` folder with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
      <string>sdkman.current</string>
      <key>CFBundleName</key>
      <string>SDKMAN Current JDK</string>
      <key>JavaVM</key>
      <dict>
          <key>JVMPlatformVersion</key>
          <string>9999</string>
          <key>JVMVendor</key>
          <string>Homebrew</string>
          <key>JVMVersion</key>
          <string>9999</string>
      </dict>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

  You can mostly use whatever `<string>` values you want in there, but note that removing any of the entries will prevent `/usr/libexec/java_home` from finding your JDK. I'm setting its version to 9999 so that its always the one returned by `/usr/libexec/java_home`.
- Check that everything works:

  ```
  ➜  /usr/libexec/java_home
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/sdkman-current/Contents/Home
  ➜  /usr/libexec/java_home -V
  Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
      9999 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "SDKMAN Current JDK" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/sdkman-current/Contents/Home
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/sdkman-current/Contents/Home
  ```

Now, stuff relying on `/usr/libexec/java_home` to find a JDK should work, including XCode Script Build Phase using `/bin/sh`.

Comment: This is also useful for people trying to open Java GUI applications using JavaLauncher.app with their installed JVM from SDKMAN! - This works like a charm

Comment: Thank you so much, was trying to build a Kotlin Multiplatform project and ran in to the same issue as you. Was halfway towards removing SDKMAN and going back to manual installs.