Upgrading from Java 11 to 17. Having problems getting mvn to work
I have followed instructions in probably a dozen Stack Overflow posts so far, but I keep ending up with the same error.
I am upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17.  I am using a Macbook Pro, Sonoma 14.4.1.  In an attempt to simplify things, I started out by uninstalling every single jdk that I had installed on my Mac.
I then installed the Java jdk for Java 17.  Java seems to be working properly.
$ java -version
java version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)

And just a sanity check:
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

But when I try to run any maven command I get this error.
$ mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

I followed the instructions in this post exactly  mvn command not found in OSX Mavericks (and a few others similar to it). But seems like no matter what I do, I keep coming back to this error.
My updated bash_profile (taken from the link in the paragraph above):
#set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/Users/myuserName/Downloads/apache-maven-3.9.7
export M2_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH


When you open Terminal and do echo $SHELL what do you get?

Is this the newest version of maven

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen might be onto something. My Maven doesn't require this

echo $SHELL gives me /usr/local/bin/bash

I went to https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and downloaded apache-maven-3.9.7

Possible regression  with 3.9.7 examined here; no problem with 3.9.6; on MacOS, try /usr/libexec/java_home -V to see installed Java versions.

/usr/libexec/java_home -V gives me Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):     17.0.11 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 17.0.11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home     9.0.4.0.11 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

When I look at homebrew for the latest maven install, I do see that maven 3.9.7 is dependent upon Java 22.

I don't do Macs but do this in Terminal to see how it works out. If it does, it can be made permanent: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home;mvn -v

That gives me the same error: The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program..  If I input 'echo $JAVA_HOME', i get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home.  I think the others are onto something with my maven version being the problem.  Trying to figure out which version of maven to downgrade to.

@noel I'm using 3.9.7 with openjdk 17. It's not a Java or maven version that needs downgrading. You need to set your JAVA_HOME correctly. Until $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version works, it's not right (and that has nothing to do with maven per se).

ok, good to know

Come at this a slightly different way. What does the following give: readlink -f "$(which javac)"?

That gives me /usr/bin/javac

Hehe, that's more than a little surprising. So what does file /usr/bin/java say?

/usr/bin/java: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/java (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/java (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e

For me that's just ... funny. That file as I usually know it is always a link. I'm going to have to leave it to the Mac people to say if that's normal. Because it in effect makes /usr into JAVA_HOME and that's just weird

After you set JAVA_HOME (and have $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version working), be sure to export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" -- I generally just use SDKman on my mac; e.g. which java gives /Users/efrisch/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java

@ElliottFrisch, that's a symlink right? And if so, to where? (Trying to get a handle on what a sane JAVA_HOME is in reality)

I modified my original post to show my bash_profile.  If I input echo JAVA_HOME, I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home which seems right to me.

I recall seeing this in the past, but (apparently) not since maven v3.5.3; you might re-examine which mvn.

JAVA_HOME looks sane but might not be. If it is right then $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac --version will work

$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac --version says javac 17.0.11.

Promising. So in theory, in the same Terminal, mvn -V should work

Exactly, and that's the mystery.  mvn -V says The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program.

which mvn gives me /Users/myuserName/Downloads/apache-maven-3.9.7/bin/mvn

Possibly worth checking: ls -l $JAVA_HOME/bin/java

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  53424 Mar 11 11:20 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

If I close my terminal, $JAVA_HOME goes away.  I just closed my terminal and now when I do echo $JAVA_HOME I get a blank line.

If I do source ~/.bash_profile, $JAVA_HOME comes back

Well if you remember we set it temporarily before, so it will. Final check: head -n 1 /Users/myuserName/Downloads/apache-maven-3.9.7/bin/mvn

#!/bin/sh

OK that was a passed sanity check. I'm out of ideas but will say that you shouldn't have to source anything. Your setting of JAVA_HOME should probably be done in ~/.bashrc

Thank you for the help.  If I do vim  ~/.bashrc, I get a blank file.

@g00se I'm using sdkman. Yes it's a link. But it's a link to /Users/efrisch/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.2.fx-librca. I do something like sdk use java 17.0.2.fx-librca to use a specific JDK. I'm also using it for maven.

./apache-maven-3.9.7/bin/mvn -v works even without JAVA_HOME set; instead of ~/.bashrc, you can try conditioning ~/.bash_profile.

3 things: 1. $JAVA_HOME/bin should be in your PATH before $PATH, as you want it to have precedence over the default PATH. 2. You should probably put your config in .bashrc instead of .bash_profile as the latter is only used for login shells. 3. Why don’t you try to just set it up with SDKMAN?


are you suggesting that the PATH should be PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH



I copied the exact same file into .bashrc.  Same problem



I'm happy to use SDKMAN if that will solve my problem.


For reference, Installing Apache Maven mentions this: "Either set the JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to your JDK installation or have the java executable on your PATH."

It occurred to me this morning that you might reinstall bash itself. Too many weird things happening. Don't ask me how though ;)

It seems that somewhere in the initialization scripts the JAVA_HOME variable is cleared explicitly (after the place where you set it). And a program or script explicitly looking for JAVA_HOME is not dependent on the PATH at all (as otherwise, it wouldn’t need the JAVA_HOME variable). So, don’t waste your time with the PATH (and, of course, the order doesn’t matter at all when there is only one JDK).

I literally can run echo $JAVA_HOME and get a response, than run mvn install and get The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this environment variable is needed to run this program. in the next line.

Another sanity check: alias mvn

-sh: alias: mvn: not found

Aww. Might have been good if it was found ;)

mvn is itself a shell script; you can see that the error is predicated on the existence and executability of $JAVACMD—via either JAVA_HOME or command -v java; you might look at how it fails or simply set to a known good value: JAVACMD=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Already done that ;)

I messed around with IntelliJ this morning.  I can run Java 17 projects within IntelliJ.  This problem only happens when I use the Mac terminal or the IntelliJ terminal

@noel you seem to have at least 2 installations according to the output of /usr/libexec/java_home -V previously given: Java 17 and Java 9. That’s why I indeed suggest to make PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH… although I figure it shouldn’t matter for Maven, since it relies only on $JAVA_HOME when it is set. Just for peace of mind: have you tried removing that Java 9?

I just realized something: since Maven relies on $JAVA_HOME and not the $PATH… I don’t think you have given the output of $JAVA_HOME/bin/java --version. Could it be that this file isn’t executable? Or even is missing? (I think it might be good to add the output of the different commands into the question itself, so that this comment section can be cleared up)

Thanks everyone for the help and comments.  Please see the answer that i just posted.  There was a hidden file that was overriding my JAVA_HOME that I discovered this afternoon while debugging.

@DidierL: when $JAVA_HOME has zero length, mvn  uses the built-in command -v java to obtain /usr/bin/java; this succeeds if /usr/bin is in the $PATH.

@trashgod yes indeed. Here we assumed that $JAVA_HOME was set, but putting it first in the path should also help with finding the right java executable. On MacOS, /usr/bin/java is not a symlink or your usual binary, it is a proprietary executable that will delegate to one of the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines (if $JAVA_HOME is not set). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652462/525036

I figured this out today while debugging with a coworker.  We compared how each of our Macs are setup and started looking for hidden files on a whim.  I found a file called ".mavenrc" in my "/Users/myusername" directory, and there was one line of text in that file that was pointing to a version of java 11 that I removed from my Mac while troubleshooting.
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/...
Once I updated this file to point to my new version of Java 17, problem solved.  'mvn -version' now works.

Ha, yes. I didn't notice that thing about mavenrc files (not mentioned in mvn --help) Good to know

Oh my, the mvn output really didn’t help here. I went ahead and created MNG-8156 in order to improve that output.
